# python: closures and classes

Tags: python, class, atexit

I need to register an `atexit` function for use with a class (see `Foo` below for an example) that, unfortunately, I have no direct way of cleaning up via a method call: other code, that I don't have control over, calls `Foo.start()` and `Foo.end()` but sometimes doesn't call `Foo.end()` if it encounters an error, so I need to clean up myself.

I could use some advice on closures in this context:

```
class Foo:
  def cleanup(self):
     # do something here
  def start(self):
     def do_cleanup():
        self.cleanup()
     atexit.register(do_cleanup)
  def end(self):
     # cleanup is no longer necessary... how do we unregister?
```

- Will the closure work properly, e.g. in `do_cleanup`, is the value of self bound correctly?
- How can I unregister an atexit() routine?
- Is there a better way to do this?

**edit**: this is Python 2.6.5

Comment: I hope that's Python 3, otherwise not inheriting from `object` gives you one of those dreaded old-style classes...

Comment: old-style? [scratches head] please elaborate so I can avoid errors

Comment: old style classes are classes from before the time classes and types were unified, if you don't inherit from `object`, you get an old style class.

Comment: So I should be declaring `class Foo(object):` ?

Comment: Yes.  See http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/.

Comment: @Glenn: :shrug: I don't have an answer that works better, and in my particular case I have only one or two instances, so technically I don't need to unregister.

Comment: Who's going to waste time giving a better answer when a poor one is accepted so quickly, without even waiting a few hours for comments?

Comment: @Glenn: if you feel like there's something wrong here, then post your own improved answer, instead of throwing out nonconstructive criticism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a registry a global registry and a function that calls a function in it, and remove them from there when necessary.

```
cleaners = set()

def _call_cleaners():
    for cleaner in list(cleaners):
        cleaner()

atexit.register(_call_cleaners)

class Foo(object):
  def cleanup(self):
     if self.cleaned:
         raise RuntimeError("ALREADY CLEANED")
     self.cleaned = True
  def start(self):
     self.cleaned = False
     cleaners.add(self.cleanup)
  def end(self):
     self.cleanup()
     cleaners.remove(self.cleanup)
```

Comment: That doesn't work: you'll get "Set changed size during iteration" if you try it. You just need to change the for loop into `for cleaner in list(cleaners)` and then it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code is fine. There's no way to unregister, but you can set a boolean flag that would disable cleanup:

```
    class Foo:
      def __init__(self):
         self.need_cleanup = True
      def cleanup(self):
         # do something here
         print 'clean up'
      def start(self):
         def do_cleanup():
            if self.need_cleanup:
               self.cleanup()
         atexit.register(do_cleanup)
      def end(self):
         # cleanup is no longer necessary... how do we unregister?
         self.need_cleanup = False
```

Lastly, bear in mind that `atexit` handlers don't get called if "[the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html)"

Comment: +1 The closure itself is pretty useless though, as you can just do `atexit.register(self.cleanup)` directly.

Comment: -1.  This will leak entries in the atexit table; if a million of these objects are created, a million items will be left behind in the atexit table permanently.  That's not fine.

Comment: This will also leak references to the object itself, which is also definitely not fine.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is bound correctly inside the callback to do_cleanup, but in fact if all you are doing is calling the method you might as well use the bound method directly.

You use `atexit.unregister()` to remove the callback, but there is a catch here as you must unregister the same function that you registered and since you used a nested function that means you have to store a reference to that function. If you follow my suggestion of using a bound method then you still have to save a reference to it:

```
class Foo:
  def cleanup(self):
     # do something here
  def start(self):
     self._cleanup = self.cleanup # Need to save the bound method for unregister
     atexit.register(self._cleanup)
  def end(self):
     atexit.unregister(self._cleanup)
```

Note that it is still possible for your code to exit without calling ther `atexit` registered functions, for example if the process is aborted with ctrl+break on windows or killed with SIGABRT on linux.

Also as another answer suggests you could just use `__del__` but that can be problematic for cleanup while a program is exiting as it may not be called until after other globals it needs to access have been deleted.

Edited to note that when I wrote this answer the question didn't specify Python 2.x. Oh well, I'll leave the answer here anyway in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Notice that atexit.unregister only exists in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Since shanked deleted his posting, I'll speak in favor of `__del__` again:

```
import atexit, weakref
class Handler:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = weakref.ref(obj)
    def cleanup(self):
        if self.obj is not None:
            obj = self.obj()
            if obj is not None:
                obj.cleanup()

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start()

    def cleanup(self):
        print "cleanup"
        self.cleanup_handler = None

    def start(self):
        self.cleanup_handler = Handler(self)
        atexit.register(self.cleanup_handler.cleanup)

    def end(self):
        if self.cleanup_handler is None:
            return
        self.cleanup_handler.obj = None
        self.cleanup()

    def __del__(self):
        self.end()

a1=Foo()
a1.end()
a1=Foo()
a2=Foo()
del a2
a3=Foo()
a3.m=a3
```

This supports the following cases:

- objects where .end is called regularly; cleanup right away
- objects that are released without .end being called; cleanup when the last
  reference goes away
- objects living in cycles; cleanup atexit
- objects that are kept alive; cleanup atexit

Notice that it is important that the cleanup handler holds a weak reference
to the object, as it would otherwise keep the object alive.

**Edit**: Cycles involving Foo will not be garbage-collected, since Foo implements `__del__`. To allow for the cycle being deleted at garbage collection time, the cleanup must be taken out of the cycle.

```
class Cleanup:
    cleaned = False
    def cleanup(self):
        if self.cleaned:
            return
        print "cleanup"
        self.cleaned = True
    def __del__(self):
        self.cleanup()

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):...
    def start(self):
        self.cleaner = Cleanup()
        atexit.register(Handler(self).cleanup)
    def cleanup(self):
        self.cleaner.cleanup()
    def end(self):
        self.cleanup()
```

It's important that the Cleanup object has no references back to Foo.

Comment: It will also keep the objects alive in case there's a cyclic reference anywhere involving it. If you are going to use `__del__` at least make that Handler object have the `__del__` method and not `Foo`, and store the weak reference to the Foo object, making the `Handler` object remove itself when the original object gets deleted.

Comment: @Rosh Oxymoron: no, having Handler implement `__del__` is no good. This objects stays until exit, since it is an atexit handler. You are right that the object won't be garbage collected when in a cycle. To support this, you need another object that does the cleanup, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it? It only took me a minute to check.

(Answer: Yes)

However, you can simplify it. The closure isn't needed.

```
class Foo:
   def cleanup(self):
      pass
   def start(self):
      atexit.register(self.cleanup)
```

And to not cleanup twice, just check in the cleanup method if a cleanup is needed or not before you clean up.

Comment: This is neat. I chose to register my cleanup call in my class init – works too.